# For a flow driven by a pump between 2 parallel, stationary plates, why is the shear force vertical and is there positive and negative shear force?

Tags: fluid-mechanics

[image]

Why is the shear force vertical when the flow is horizontal? Also, why is the shear force at the top surface of the control volume negative and the bottom is positive when they are both in the same direction?

Comment: I don't see any shear forces in the given diagram.  I only see 4 normal forces.  Remember, normal forces are perpendicular to the face and shear forces are parallel (tangential) to the face.  Not sure if that's just typo, or if it alters the way you are thinking about this problem.